# How do I add extra validation to regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex string:

```
r'^[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яЇїІіЄєҐґ:?!\-\+\(\)\.,ʼ=№#& ]+$'
```

I want to add extra validation to it: Special characters cannot go one after another (e.g., there can be no ".,",!"..", etc.). However, the special characters can be followed by a single space (e.g., ", ". "? ", etc.). The exception is that there cannot be a space after a space, i.e. 2 spaces in a row

Chatgpt didn't help at all, every time I tried to correct it's answear it generated brand new regex (not valid)

Comment: It helps if you provide some examples of what would be allowed and not allowed.

Comment: You need to list the characters that you regard as *special characters*. Suppose they are `'.'`, `','` and `'!'`. Then you can ensure that there will be no two special characters in a row by inserting the following *negative lookahead* right after the start of sting anchor, `^`: `(?!.*[.,!]{2})`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason this needs to be a single regular expression. It'd be much more straightforward to use two: the one you already have, which checks for allowable characters, and a second, which checks for the additional restrictions.

For example, you can check for a string that contains either two spaces in a row or two special characters in a row (not including spaces) like this:

```
r" {2}|[:?!\-+().,]{2}"
```

Then you just check to make sure the string matches the first regex and *doesn't* match the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?!.*[.,!]{2})(?!.*  )[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яЇїІіЄєҐґ:?!\-+().,ʼ=№#& ]+$
```

Here I added two negative lookahead groups: they prevent matching if beginning of the string(`^`) is followed by:

- two special character (here any of `.,!`, you can change accordingly to you needs)
- two spaces.

Additionally, I removed redundant escaping in you symbol class.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do all that validation in one regex will result in a very complex regex that will be pretty inscrutable to future maintainers. You might be better off performing multiple checks using code.

```
base = re.compile(r'^[A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-яЇїІіЄєҐґ:?!\-\+\(\)\.,ʼ=№#& ]+$')
double_special = re.compile(r'[-:?!+()\.,=№#& ]{2}') 
...
if base.match(some_string) and not double_special.match(some_string):
   ... string is OK ...
else:
   ... string is not OK ...
```

The `double_special` regex above matches two special characters *or* two spaces.